# How to create a link inside of CTreeview node with confirmation in YII?

Tags: yii

I am using CTreeview, and to manage nodes of the Tree I'm adding some icons with a link. E.g.:

```
$addButtonImage = CHtml::image(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/images/add.png', '', array('width'=>'12', 'height'=>'12', 'class'=>'button'));
$delButtonImage = CHtml::image(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/images/delete.png', '', array('width'=>'12', 'height'=>'12', 'class'=>'del_button'));
$editButtonImage = CHtml::image(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/images/edit.png', '', array('width'=>'12', 'height'=>'12', 'class'=>'button'));
```

And for the delete icon I would like to ask a confirmation. But the following code:

```
$nodeText = CHtml::link($delButtonImage, array('treeMenu/delete', 'id'=>$treenode['id']), array("confirm"=>"Are you sure?"));
```

does not help, and even a confirmation dialog does not appear.

But if I write a code like:

```
$nodeText = CHtml::link($delButtonImage, array('treeMenu/delete', 'id'=>$treenode['id']), array('onclick'=>'confirmDeleteNode()'));
```

it shows a confirmation dialog, but even if I press Cancel button on that dialog, it goes to the deleting link and delete my node. How can I solve these my problem?

Comment: If I add the confirmation dialog directly inside the code not like a JS function, it works:

`$nodeText .= CHtml::link($delButtonImage, array('treeMenu/delete', 'id'=>$treenode['id']), array('onclick'=>'return confirm ("You are deleteing the node with the id ?");'));`

Comment: found the answer. Just need to add keyword return before my JS function, like this: '$nodeText .= CHtml::link($delButtonImage, array('treeMenu/delete', 'id'=>$treenode['id']), array('onclick'=>'return confirmDeleteNode()'));'. Sometimes it is useful to ask aloud in forums :)